# After earned "close and reopen votes" i can't do a normal flag?

Tags: support, flagging

After i earned the **"close and reopen votes"** i can't do a normal flag only close flag is this normal?

I select flag for a question and than select

> Needs improvement
>
> This question needs updates from the author in order to be answered well or belongs on another Stack Exchange site.

after I select that

> This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

I see only the **Vote to close** no longer **Flag question**

Is this they way i have to flag now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. You now have the right to directly vote, so there is no need to flag, the flag just says "I would vote, but I can't, so please check this out for me". You are now trusted enough to be able to vote directly and there is no longer a need to flag, so please go ahead and vote.